# Associating multiple extensions with a single file

Tags: file, filesystems, metadata, filenames, file-extension

I want to associate multiple extensions with the same file so that if you change the file extension different content is revealed. For example, a file named `file1.jpg` contains an image and when you change the extension to `file1.txt` it opens as a text file.

I know it may seem strange (why not have two separate files?) but it’s for an easter egg in a project I’m doing. Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote - it's an interesting problem, if not exactly useful.  Microsoft even implemented [alternate data streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams) to do something like this.

Comment: Can creating a symbolic link (`ln -fs file1.jpg file1.txt`) achieve what you wanted ?

Comment: @Philippe I’m not well versed but my understanding is symlinking would only work for my system, and I’d like to be able to share the file with someone else.